# Change existing macro to copy formulas from specific columns

Tags: vba, excel

This is my still my first macro, I have been searching like a mad man trying to get this to work...and it's getting close!

I have it set to copy "Pricing_Cost" sheet from Active workbook into a new workbook as values and then manipulate it beyond that.  What I really need is to modify that step so that certain columns copy values, others copy formulas.  I have columns A:X

Columns needing to be pasted as values = A,E,F,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,T,U,V,W,X

Columns needing to pasted as formula = B,C,D,G,O,P,Q,R,S

This is within the CopyRemoveFormSave sub

I'm guessing maybe I should copy the whole thing as formulas and then cut and paste as values the columns that need to be converted to values?  Not really sure how to do that with the code I have here...

```
    Public strFile As String
Sub RunAll()
    Call load_csv
    Call CopyRemoveFormAndSave
    Call Splitbook
End Sub
Sub load_csv()

    Dim fStr As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Cancel Selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'fStr is the file path and name of the file you selected.
    fStr = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

Sheets("Product_Weekly").UsedRange.ClearContents

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Product_Weekly").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"TEXT;" & fStr, Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Product_Weekly").Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "CAPTURE"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With
End Sub


Declare PtrSafe Function GetTempPath Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTempPathA" _
(ByVal nBufferLength As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long

Private Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260

'~~> Function to get user's temp directoy
Function TempPath() As String
    TempPath = String$(MAX_PATH, Chr$(0))
    GetTempPath MAX_PATH, TempPath
    TempPath = Replace(TempPath, Chr$(0), "")
End Function


Sub CopyRemoveFormAndSave()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsName As String, NewName As String
'    Dim shp As Shape

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

wsName = ActiveSheet.Name

NewName = wsName & ".xlsm"

wb.SaveCopyAs TempPath & NewName

Set wbNew = Workbooks.Open(TempPath & NewName)

wbNew.Sheets(wsName).UsedRange.Value = wbNew.Sheets(wsName).UsedRange.Value

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws In wbNew.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> wsName Then ws.Delete
Next ws
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'    For Each shp In wbNew.Sheets(wsName).Shapes
'        If shp.Type = 8 Then shp.Delete
'    Next

'
'~~> Do a save as for the new workbook if required.
'
'End Sub

Columns("W:W").Replace "2", "KevinClark", xlWhole
Columns("W:W").Replace "9", "PaulG", xlWhole
Columns("W:W").Replace "O", "KevinClark", xlWhole
Columns("W:W").Replace "I", "KevinClark", xlWhole
Columns("W:W").Replace "4", "PaulG", xlWhole
Columns("W:W").Replace "8", "KevinClark", xlWhole
Columns("W:W").Replace "7", "KevinClark", xlWhole


'Sub SplitData()
Const NameCol = "W"
Const HeaderRow = 3
Const FirstRow = 4
Dim SrcSheet As Worksheet
Dim TrgSheet As Worksheet
Dim SrcRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim TrgRow As Long
Dim Buyer As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set SrcSheet = ActiveSheet
LastRow = SrcSheet.Cells(SrcSheet.Rows.Count, NameCol).End(xlUp).Row
For SrcRow = FirstRow To LastRow
    Buyer = SrcSheet.Cells(SrcRow, NameCol).Value
    Set TrgSheet = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set TrgSheet = Worksheets(Buyer)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TrgSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set TrgSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
        TrgSheet.Name = Buyer
'            SrcSheet.Range(HeaderRow).Copy Destination:=TrgSheet.Range(HeaderRow)
        SrcSheet.Range("A1:W3").Copy Destination:=TrgSheet.Range("A1:W3")
    End If
    TrgRow = TrgSheet.Cells(TrgSheet.Rows.Count, NameCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    SrcSheet.Rows(SrcRow).Copy Destination:=TrgSheet.Rows(TrgRow)
Next SrcRow
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Dim sht As Worksheet

''AutoFit One Column
'    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("O:O").EntireColumn.AutoFit
'
''AutoFit Multiple Columns
'    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I:I,L:L").EntireColumn.AutoFit 'Columns I & L
'    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I:L").EntireColumn.AutoFit 'Columns I to L
'
''AutoFit All Columns on Worksheet
'    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

'AutoFit Every Worksheet Column in a Workbook
For Each sht In wbNew.Worksheets
    sht.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Next sht


End Sub

Sub Splitbook()
'Updateby20140612
Dim xPath As String
xPath = "C:\Users\Jimbo.JAMESP-ACERLT\Documents\For Gary\Output"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each xWs In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If xWs.Name <> "Pricing Cost" Then
    xWs.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xlsx"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    End If
  Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say I think the best step is to copy all as formulas initially. What I would do next is define an array which contains the column letters which you need to be values, you can do that as follows.

```
ValArr = Array("A","E","F","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","T","U","V","W","X")
```

Then you can loop through this array and turn each column to values.

```
For x = Lbound(ValArr) To Ubound(ValArr)
    'Paste values in column ValArr(x)
Next
```

I hope this helps, let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: for clarification, wbNew.Sheets(wsName).UsedRange.Value = wbNew.Sheets(wsName).UsedRange.Value is the statement that is changing all cells to values right now?

Comment: That's right, so instead within the loop you can use wbNew.Sheets(wsName).Columns(ValArr(x)).Value = wbNew.Sheets(wsName).Columns(ValArr(x)).Value or code to that effect. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: More complex than I thought, My original sheet has dependencies on another sheet in that workbook.  My code now copy's original sheet values to the new workbook.  I need to change original columns to values before sheet is copied to new workbook so I don't lose the data and get #REF?.  What I liked about my current code is the original sheet was left unchanged.  

I'm thinking if I duplicate the original sheet as a temp sheet, run your loop to convert columns in ValArr to values, save and open the temp sheet in new workbook and delete tempsheet from original workbook and continue my macro.

Comment: Just so my understanding is correct, you're getting formula errors after the sheet has been copied to the new workbook? If that's the case then what you're describing should work, create a temporary sheet etc.

Comment: yes, the original sheet pulls most of its data from another sheet, hence why they need to be converted to values.  This is one heck of a learning experience for me haha

Comment: But copy and paste works? I would say that's a separate question something like "how to dynamically change formula sheet references."

Comment: I've actually solved it by recording a macro and doing by hand copy paste, and just copying the generated code.  Final question, now that I have correct values/formulas for each column, what can I change the statement

wbNew.Sheets(wsName).UsedRange.Value = wbNew.Sheets(wsName).UsedRange.Value

to so that it just copies data as it is, not converting to values

Comment: As @Charlie stated below, if you use .Formula instead of .Value if there is a formula it will copy that, else it will just copy the text. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without any copy and pasting. For example let's say you want to copy all the formulas from Sheet1 to Sheet2 you can do something like this:

```
for i = 1 to lastRow
    for j in 1 to lastCol
        Sheets("Sheet2").cells(i,j).formula = Sheets("Sheet1").cells(i,j).formula
    next j
next i
```

Also if there's no formula it just copies the text so you can do that for all the cells.

Comment: I get what this is doing but not sure how to apply it.  I've got it creating the temp sheet with no dependencies and values/formulas as they should be....now I need this temp sheet opened in a new workbook as it appears.  The code I'm using now is wbNew.Sheets(wsName).UsedRange.Value = wbNew.Sheets(wsName).UsedRange.Value which will not work for that

Comment: ahhh change .Value to .Formula ..let's try that!

Comment: I've made incredible progress on this, big thanks to everyone for helping me !